# Xyz coordinate from distance

Tags: math, geometry

If i have 3 points in xyz plane 
I know the distance between them and the coordinates of two of them 
What is the equation that can let me find the coordinates of the last point ??

Comment: If you have two points and a distance to a unknown third point, there are infinitely many possible third points, unless they are all three on a straight line.

Comment: I have 2 points and the distance between the three points but i want an equation to find the third point coordinates

Comment: What is the xyz plane? Do you mean a plane in 3D space? Then there are still two possible solutions.

Comment: I might be wrong but there should be an entire circle of possible solutions

Comment: I think understand. You have 3 points _A_, _B_ and _C_ in 3D space. You know two of the point's, let's say _A_ and _B_ coordinates and the distance of _C_ to them. Find the coordinates of _C_. The're are two solutions to this problem with a mirror line along _AB_.

Comment: Maybe this questions needs to be asked in [Mathematics.SE] first to get the math down, and then ask here if there is a specific implementiation question with the language of your choice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

You have two fixed points *A* and *B* with distance `l` between them.

You have a third point *C* with only known distances to *A* and *B* as `a` and `b` respectively.

You find the angle `γ=angle(ACB)` using the [cosine rule](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/geometry/furthertrigonometryhirev2.shtml)

```
γ = ACOS( (a^2+b^2-l^2)/(2*a*b) )
```

Now you find the distance `h` of point *C* to the line *AB*

```
h = a*b*SIN(γ)/l
```

Lastly you find the other two angles of the triangle. The angle `α` has vertex *A* and angle `β` has vertex *B*.

```
α = ASIN(h/a)
β = ASIN(h/b)
```

You can find the coordinates of *C* using the distance & angle formulas you have in polar coordinates.